# aChartEngine doesn't show graph in Android

Tags: android, achartengine

This is my LineGraph code:

```
package com.example.testgraph;

import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
import org.achartengine.GraphicalView;
import org.achartengine.model.TimeSeries;
import org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
import org.achartengine.model.XYSeries;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYSeriesRenderer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     private GraphicalView mChartView;
     private XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
      /** The main renderer that includes all the renderers customizing a chart. */
      private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
      /** The most recently added series. */
      private XYSeries mCurrentSeries;
      /** The most recently created renderer, customizing the current series. */
      private XYSeriesRenderer mCurrentRenderer;
      /** Button for creating a new series of data. */
      private Button mNewSeries;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout mGraphParent = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.graphParent);


        int x [] = {1,2,3};  
        int y [] = {30,40,50};  

        TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Line1");
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length;i++)
        {
            series.add(x[i],y[i]);

        } 
        Log.d("line","graph");
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataSet = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        dataSet.addSeries(series);
        XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);




          mChartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, dataSet, mRenderer);
          // enable the chart click events
          mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
          mRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(10);

          mGraphParent.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
              LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

          mChartView.repaint();


    } 

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

This is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/graphParent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The graph just doesn't show up on screen and I've no clue where I'm going wrong in this trivial implementation.

Comment: What does it display?

Comment: I only see the zoom buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used AChartEngine but I can suggest three ways to debug this.

1. Read the docs and see how the instructions differ from your code.
2. Replicate one of the examples linked from [the project's home page](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/). [This example](http://www.javaadvent.com/2012/12/achartengine-charting-library-for.html) is short. The [project's demos](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/#svn/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo) are longer demos of its features. Once that works you can incrementally evolve and test it.
3. Think of hypotheses that explain the problem, then test those hypotheses one by one. E.g. maybe mChartView is not visible in the layout. You could test that by setting its background color. Maybe the view is visible but the entire graph is black on black. You could test that by picking different colors. Since multiple things could be broken, it's a good idea to simplify the program to the bare minimum first.

P.S. Java convention is to write `int[] x = ...` to declare int array `x`. The older syntax is only there to make it easier for C programmers to start using Java.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use version 1.2 of aChartEngine library